# Filter DataFrame for numeric values

Tags: python, pandas, filter, numeric

Let's assume my `DataFrame` `df` has a column called `col` of type `string`. What is wrong with the following code line?

```
df['col'].filter(str.isnumeric)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```
df.loc[df['col'].str.isnumeric()]
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a short and good solution to what I wanted to achieve. However, since I want to learn pandas better I'm interested: Is there a solution to the problem using the pandas filter method?

Answer (score 1):

First problem, you're using a *built-in* python method without parenthesis which is [`str.isnumeric`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric). Hence, the `TypeError: 'method_descriptor' object is not iterable`.

Second problem, let's suppose you've added parenthesis to `str.isnumeric`, this function needs one argument/string to check if all characters in the given string are numeric characters. Hence the `TypeError: unbound method str.isnumeric() needs an argument`.

Third problem, let's suppose you've fixed **1)** and **2)**, since this function returns a boolean (`True` *or* `False`), you cannot pass it as a first parameter of pandas *built-in* method [`pandas.Series.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.filter.html). Hence, the `TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable`.

As per the documentation, the first parameter needs to be a list-like :

> items: list-like
> Keep labels from axis which are in items.

In your case, I believe you want to use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html) with [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['foo', 'bar 123', '456']})
m = df['col'].str.isnumeric()
out = df.loc[m]
```

Output:

```
print(out)
   col
2  456
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean with "without parenthesis". Do you mean those at the end like `str.isnumeric()`?

Comment: Yes, those are the parenthesis I'm talking about.

Comment: In order to learn pandas better I'm looking for a solution using the filter method. I also tried to use a lambda expression. Can you make my filtering work with the pandas filter method even though masking is of course a lot easier?

Comment: The documentation says about `pandas.DataFrame.filter`: _Note that this routine **does not filter a dataframe on its contents**. The filter is applied to the labels of the index._ So, unfortunaltely you can't achieve what you're looking for unless you set the column `col` as an index an then filter on the `axis=0`, something like this :  `df.set_index("col").filter(regex="(?!.[a-zA-Z])^.*$", axis=0)`. But you need to ensure that regex pattern used will pick only numeric rows..